# Создать запрос в nginx

Tags: postgresql, nginx, websocket

Можно ли в nginx создать запрос?

Имеются два модуля nginx: один работает с веб-сокетами, а второй с базой данных постгрес.

Чтобы отправить сообщение в веб-сокет - надо выполнить запрос на определённый location (первого модуля)

Второй же модуль может получать от базы асинхронные уведомления (listen/notify)

И теперь надо как-то при получении асинхронного уведомления во втором модуле как-то создать запрос, который вызовет location первого модуля, чтобы тот отправил данные в веб-сокет

Можно ли это как-то сделать? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Уопать в сторону lua.  Хотя вообще идея программировать на nginx так себе

Comment: не хочу lua: если lua - тогда уж лучше сразу tarantool

Comment: применил curl_easy, но т.к. он синхронный и отправляет запрос на тот же nginx - nginx самоблокируется :(

Comment: Ну ещё njs есть.